# Unable to console event in select change and code performance issue ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, firefox

Following is my code, which was working fine till I added `changePagesize` method and trying to console `e` event. Site stops responding in `Firefox`. Let me know what I am doing wrong and why message is not consoling.

Full Code - [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-nobel-uomuk?file=/src/App.js:484-498)

Code -

```
const changePagesize = e => {
    e.persist();
    console.log(`Element`, e);
    setPagesize(e.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need it but just remove e.persist() and it will work as expected.

```
const changePagesize = e => {
    const { preventDefault, stopPropagation } = e;
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    console.log(`prevent`, preventDefault);
    console.log(`stop`, stopPropagation);

    console.log(`name`, name);
    console.log(`value`, value);
    // e.persist();

    setPagesize(e.target.value);
  };
```

You can destructure it like this if you know what values you need from (e).

Comment: If I remove or comment `e.persist()` I am getting warnings in console.

Comment: Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `type` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

Comment: But why `e.persist()` is causing performance issue ?